# Why won't Autocad print georefenced jpeg that is reduced?

Tags: r, jpeg, geospatial, tiff, autocad

So, on my projects I require an aerial photo of a site. I usually use ones in public record. I use the USGS high res ortho photos located here https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/. I have them uploaded to my server and they are TIFs and have TFWs and XMLs associated with them (I am unsure of what the xml is for). I can load these into autocad fine, and print them just fine. average file size of these appears to be in the 250,000 kb range.

On some of my projects, I need more detail. I get privately flown aerial photos of a site. These come as a JPG format and are georefernced by a .jgw. These files are about 25000 kb depending on the site ( I did not notice this at first, as i was told they are very large relative to the TIFs). When these are loaded into autocad and i try to plot, the whole system freezed and wont plot for about 15-20 mins. At first I thought this was a file size issue. So I did the following in R, to try to reduce the size. My code is as follows.

```
library(jpeg)
library(tiff)
img <- readJPEG("ortho.jpg", native = TRUE)
writeJPEG(img, quality = 0.2)'
```

This got the file size down to about 9000 kb. I loaded this into autocad and it still would not plot. This leads me to assume that size is not the issue. With this is mind what could be a property of this photo that would freeze autocad? How could I fix those properties in R or in Autocad.

Comment: Sounds like an autocad bug.

Comment: What are you plotting to, PDF or paper?  If you're plotting to paper, make sure your plotter has it's spooling set correctly as it could be an issue with your plotter running out of memory.

Comment: I am plotting to paper, and I don't believe the memory on the printer is an issue because I print geotiffs of the same format, provided by my local county, that are much larger.

Answer (score 0):

First I would check out the first and third causes listed here: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Some-OLE-objects-do-not-plot.html and see if that fixes your issue.

Second I would convert to a png (in my limited experience those seem to be the most stable in autocad.)

```
library(png)
writePNG(img)
```

If you really need it in jpg I would try the solutions here too: https://www.landfx.com/kb/autocad-fxcad/images/item/1926-raster-disappear.html

Comment: Is there a way to reference a png in a way that is similar to jpg or tif were there is a .jgw or .twf? I know to switch a reference between those two, it is simply a name change.